# get notification when new iOS application installed iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, notifications

I wondered if there are a way to be notified when a new application is installed in my device and trigger some treatment in my applications. Like PACKAGE_ADDED BroadcastReceiver in android
Thank's

Comment: No this isn't possible. Each app is sandboxed in its own little environment so the only apps it knows about is the one you have made and that is running. Also you can't do anything outside of that environment and what you are after would need to be done outside each environment to detect when the app is installed. So no luck mate.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide such information. Instead, you could add something like:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"firstRun"] == nil)
{
 //This is a first run
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NotFirstRun" forKey:@"firstRun"];
}
```

to `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

**update**

If you instead want to detect the installation of another app the approach is different:
You can't detect when an app is installed, but for SOME apps you can detect if they are installed.
Doing your own app launch (or perhaps using a backgroundfetch process) you can see if an app is installed IF the app responds to a URL Scheme AND you know that scheme.
Take a look at

```
([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
```

If this methode returns `YES` for a given URL Scheme you know that app is installed. [Here is a partial list of URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Registering_your_own_URL_schemes) for some common apps or search http://handleopenurl.com/. You can of course also make your own URL Scheme if you want to detect your own app.

Comment: I think OP was looking for some notifications when any other new application is installed. This detects first launch of its own application.

Answer (score 0):

No. Apple doesn't give you this data.

What you can do, however, is maintain an user defaults data and manipulate in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a library called '`GBVersionTracking`' for detect when is his first launch.

Importing this library you can send messages to the class '`GBVersionTracking`' like:

```
[GBVersionTracking isFirstLaunchEver];              
[GBVersionTracking isFirstLaunchForVersion];        
[GBVersionTracking isFirstLaunchForBuild];
```

https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBVersionTracking

Comment: I don't think you understand @yas12 's problem.